# Having trouble with React rendering a series of images from a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I'm trying to design a component where the user can click a button which will trigger a giphy API call that will eventually render a series of gif images.

So far I'm able to successfully get everything done except the actual image rendering. Here's my code so far:

```
retrieveURLs() {
    *bunch of stuff to make API call and return an array of URLs related 
    to the category of the button the user pushes* 
}
renderGifs() {
    this.retrieveURLs().then(function(results) {
        console.log(results); //logs array of URLs  
        return results.map(function(url, index) {
            console.log(url); //logs each url
            return (<img key={index} src={url} alt="" />)
        }, this);   
    });
}
render() {
    return(
        <div id="gif-div">
            {this.renderGifs()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Nothing gets rendered despite each console.log() event indicating that the URL(s) are at least being passed properly.

I do something similar for the parent component to render the buttons from an array of categories that looks like this:

```
btnArray = [*bunch of categories here*];
renderButtons() {
    return btnArray.map(function(item, i) {
        let btnID = btnArray[i].replace(/\s+/g, "+");
        return <button type='button' className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.handleCategorySelect} key={i} id={btnID} value={btnID}>{btnArray[i]}</button>
    }, this)
}
```

The buttons are rendered properly, but my images are not. Neither the renderbuttons nor the rendergifs metohds alter the state. Honestly I can't see a meaningful difference between the two, so I'd like to have some help figuring out why one works but the other doesn't.

Comment: are you sure these `img` tags are not rendered in the page? maybe the url is empty or wrong...

Comment: Yep. Nothing is being rendered to the page inside the div element that the images are supposed to be nested in.

Answer (score 3):

This is the nature of asynchronous functions; you can't return a value from within a callback to the original call site. If you were to write:

```
const res = this.retrieveURLs().then(function(results) {
    return results;
});
```

you'd only be changing the resolution value of the promise. `res` won't be assigned the value of `results`, but rather it will be assigned the **promise** created by `this.retrieveURLs()`, and the only way to retrieve the value of a resolved promise is by attaching a `.then` callback.

What you could do is this:

```
this.retrieveURLs().then(results => {
    this.setState({ images: results });  
});
```

Now your internal state will be updated asynchronously, and your component will be told to re-render with the new data, which you can use in your render function by accessing the state.

**Note:** I'm using an arrow function to create the callback in the above example, because otherwise `this` won't be bound to the right context. Alternatively, you could do the old `that = this` trick, or use `Function#bind`.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, 1) the renderButtons() method works because it relies on an array that is already defined when the component is rendered (and is independent of the state), but the renderGifs() method doesn't work because it relies on the result of an API call that comes from a  state (this.state.category) change. 2) Thus, once the (category) state is changed, the component is already rendered and the promise has no effect on the state (and therefore the component). Is that right?

Comment: `renderButtons` works because it synchronously returns the JSX to the `render` method, by reading the existing array at the time it's executed. Nothing needs to wait for some asynchronous task to complete. `renderGifs()` **doesn't** work because it's not immediately returning the JSX; it returns `undefined`, and thus React renders nothing. So you have no choice but to request that React re-render the component in the promise's callback. The way to do this is to use `setState()` (state changes automatically cause components to re-render unless `shouldComponentUpdate` says otherwise).

Comment: It seems like you might have some misconceptions in your mental image of how this stuff is working, so we can move this to chat if my comment above didn't fully sort things out. (**oops**, or I guess we can discuss here until it's automatically moved to chat, didn't realize you couldn't do that manually!).

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with the rendering function for the images and the way React does diffing between the previous and current state. Since the fetch is asynchronous  and the render is not, when the fetch is completed React doesn't know that it needs to re-render you component. There are ways to force a re-render in this case, but a better solution is to use the functionality that's already part of the `shouldUpdate` check.

Your implementation might change to look something like the following:

```
class Images extends Component {
  state = {
    images: [],
    error: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return this.retrieveImages()
      .then(images => this.setState({images}))
      .catch(error => this.setState({error}))
  }

  ... rest of your class definition

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.images.map(image => <img src={image.url} />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I would also have some handling for bad results, missing key / values, etc. I hope that works for you, if not let me know! :)

Comment: Yes, even if the promise itself was returned from `renderGifs`, React doesn't support rendering a promise (though that would be interesting).

Comment: Totally untested, but wondering if you could do something like

```
async render() {
  return (<div>{await renderImages()}</div>)
}
```

without it breaking stuff.

Comment: Looks like declaring `async render() { ... }` causes an invariant violation in React, but it was a nice try. :-)

Comment: It does help, so thank you. The core of your answer clarifies what I needed to know. I can't quite implement your code as-is, though, because the component is rendered without a subject (retrieveURLs() defines the subject for the API call by `let subject = this.props.category`, which is undefined until a user presses a button) from the parent component, so the componentDidMount will always return an error (unless I'm misunderstanding something).

Answer (score 0):

first of all you forgot the return statement:

```
renderGifs() {
    return this.retrieveURLs().then(function(results) {
...
}
```

but this won't solve anything as it is returning a `Promise`.

You need to save request results in the state and then map it:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = { images: [] };
}

componentDidMount() {
   this.renderGifs();
}

renderGifs() {
    this.retrieveURLs().then(function(results) {
        console.log(results); //logs array of URLs  
        this.stateState({ images: results }); 
    });
}

render() {
    return(
        <div id="gif-div">
            {
              this.state.images.map((url, index) => (<img key={index} src={url} alt="" />);
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```